# Do bachelor programs in Germany with no Numerus Clausus accept any a level grades?

Tags: graduate-admissions, undergraduate, germany

I am planning to apply to a bachelor program in Germany with no *Numerus Clausus*, using my cambridge A-levels.

If I am eligible for a direct admission, does this mean that I can be sure that I will be accepted regardless of my A-levels grades?

Comment: I have no idea why anyone would downvote this question. It is obviously a specific question, asked in good faith.

Comment: I agree. Perhaps the sloppy spelling?

Comment: One reason to close this question is that it's about undergraduate admissions.

Comment: @AlexB. seems to me that it's a perfectly good question, but it's about undergrad admissions, which are specifically listed as off-topic in our help section. That's ideally a reason to flag it for closure rather than to downvote, though.

Answer (score 4):

According to the German Constitution, (Art. 12 GG), every German has the right to chose their own education institution, if they have the formal qualification. Under the European principles of free movement and non-discrimination, this effectively includes foreign EU citizens.

Therefore, *if there is no Numerus Clausus*, this *usually* means that every EU citizen with an Abitur or equivalent foreign degree will be admitted to the study program and at the education institution of their own chosing.

However:

- There may be additional language requirements for foreigners.
- There may be additional selection criteria, defined by the local university, for study programs that are offered only at few institutions.
- The recognition of UK A levels as equivalent for the purpose of university admissions may become an issue after Brexit.

To be on the safe side, you should contact the student [advisory service](https://www.hochschulkompass.de/en/degree-programmes/choosing-a-programme/student-advisory-service.html) of the university at which you are planning to apply well in advance.

Comment: In addition, there will be some process for getting your A-levels as formally recognized as sufficient. As henning wrote, this should be no problem, but I would expect an additional administrative process. The student advisory service *or* the international office of the university should be your point of contacts.